# Winston - Multiple console transport

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I'm trying to use winston for logging in node.

I want to log exceptions in console for `production` mode while logging all the events for `development` mode.

here's my logger.js file

```
const winston = require('winston');
const path = require('path');

//Get logging level
const level = process.env.log || 'debug';

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

function printf (info) {
  return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level} [${info.label}]: ${info.message}`
}

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  exitOnError: false,
  level: level,
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.label({ label: path.basename(process.mainModule.filename) }),
    winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' })
  ),
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      handleExceptions: true,
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        winston.format.printf(info => `${printf(info)}` )
      )
    }),
  ]
});

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
  logger.add(
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        winston.format.printf(info => `${printf(info)}` )
      )
    })
  );

module.exports = logger;
```

Unfortunately, Whenever I am trying to log an unhandled exception, all I see is `undefined` in console without any error details.

Can somebody please help?